# JPA not working as expected even though it seems a simple JPQL call

Tags: java, docker, eclipselink, apache-tomee, java-10

***JPA not working as expected even though it seems a simple JPQL call:***

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e
```

***...but, getting this exception (from system log after GET operation)...***

*Note the EL WARNING:  "Model classes may not have been found during entity search"...*

```
-
-
-
[EL Info]: 2018-09-19 12:21:37.142--ServerSession(301360221)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--/file:/usr/local/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/MyRestSvc/WEB-INF/classes/_DB2JPA login successful
[EL Warning]: 2018-09-19 12:21:37.144--ServerSession(301360221)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--Problem while registering MBean: java.lang.NullPointerException
[EL Warning]: 2018-09-19 12:21:37.156--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM Employee e]. 
[14, 22] The abstract schema type 'Employee' is unknown.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1764)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:387)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.typedProxyIfNoTx(JtaEntityManager.java:382)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:454)
    at aaa.bbb.ccc.war.MyRestSvc.get(MyRestSvc.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
-
-
-
```

Any ideas/suggestions to help solve this issue would be appreciated.  Wondering if there is some incompatibilty with EclipseLink version 2.7.1 and how the model classes are generated via the Eclipse (photon) ide.

***I'm using the db2sampl database that comes bundled with db2express-c...***

***Here is tomee.xml declaring the resource...***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<tomee>
    <Resource id="jdbc/sample" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        driverClassName com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
        jdbcDriverType  4
        url         jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE
        username        db2inst1
        password        db2inst1-pwd
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

***Here is the persistence.xml...***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DB2JPA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/SAMPLE</jta-data-source>
        <class>aaa.bbb.ccc.model.Department</class>
        <class>aaa.bbb.ccc.model.Employee</class>
        <class>aaa.bbb.ccc.model.Staff</class>      
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>      
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***Here are the model classes (created using Eclipse: Entities generated from tables)...***

**Employee.java...**

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the EMPLOYEE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=6)
    private String empno;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column(precision=9, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal bonus;

    @Column(name="\"COMM\"", precision=9, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal comm;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private short edlevel;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=12)
    private String firstnme;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date hiredate;

    @Column(length=8)
    private String job;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=15)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(length=1)
    private String midinit;

    @Column(length=4)
    private String phoneno;

    @Column(precision=9, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal salary;

    @Column(length=1)
    private String sex;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Department
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Department> departments;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Department
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="WORKDEPT")
    private Department department;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public String getEmpno() {
        return this.empno;
    }

    public void setEmpno(String empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return this.birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBonus() {
        return this.bonus;
    }

    public void setBonus(BigDecimal bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public BigDecimal getComm() {
        return this.comm;
    }

    public void setComm(BigDecimal comm) {
        this.comm = comm;
    }

    public short getEdlevel() {
        return this.edlevel;
    }

    public void setEdlevel(short edlevel) {
        this.edlevel = edlevel;
    }

    public String getFirstnme() {
        return this.firstnme;
    }

    public void setFirstnme(String firstnme) {
        this.firstnme = firstnme;
    }

    public Date getHiredate() {
        return this.hiredate;
    }

    public void setHiredate(Date hiredate) {
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return this.job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getMidinit() {
        return this.midinit;
    }

    public void setMidinit(String midinit) {
        this.midinit = midinit;
    }

    public String getPhoneno() {
        return this.phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return this.sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        return this.departments;
    }

    public void setDepartments(List<Department> departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }

    public Department addDepartment(Department department) {
        getDepartments().add(department);
        department.setEmployee(this);

        return department;
    }

    public Department removeDepartment(Department department) {
        getDepartments().remove(department);
        department.setEmployee(null);

        return department;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return this.department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

**Department.java...**

```
(removed for space - can provide on request)
```

**Staff.java...**

```
(removed for space - can provide on request)
```

***This is the REST service - just a GET method (for simplicity)...***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.war;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import aaa.bbb.ccc.model.Employee;

@Stateless
@Path("/employeeList")
public class MyRestSvc {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DB2JPA")
    EntityManager em;

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    public MyRestSvc() {
    }


    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Employee> get(@Context javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request) {

        em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); // Invalidate all objects in the cache

        List<Employee> eList = null;

        try {
            eList = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e").getResultList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        return eList;
    }

}
```

***Here is the log on Tomee startup...***

```
(removed for space - can provide on request)
```

***Here is the system log ouput/reaction to GET operation...***

```
[EL Info]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.756--ServerSession(174651846)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f
[EL Fine]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.765--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2Platform
[EL Config]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.777--ServerSession(174651846)--Connection(393909340)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DatabasePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.778--ServerSession(174651846)--Connection(935474207)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE
    User: db2inst1
    Database: DB2/LINUXX8664  Version: SQL10055
    Driver: IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ  Version: 4.21.29
[EL Config]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.778--ServerSession(174651846)--Connection(247275895)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DB2Platform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.791--ServerSession(174651846)--Connection(1852461265)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE
    User: db2inst1
    Database: DB2/LINUXX8664  Version: SQL10055
    Driver: IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ  Version: 4.21.29
[EL Info]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.796--ServerSession(174651846)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--/file:/usr/local/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/webapps/MyRestSvc/WEB-INF/classes/_DB2JPA login successful
[EL Warning]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.799--ServerSession(174651846)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--Problem while registering MBean: java.lang.NullPointerException
[EL Warning]: 2018-09-19 07:05:43.806--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-1,5,main])--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM Employee e]. 
[14, 22] The abstract schema type 'Employee' is unknown.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1743)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:387)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.proxyIfNoTx(JtaEntityManager.java:375)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.createQuery(JtaEntityManager.java:329)
    at aaa.bbb.ccc.war.MyRestSvc.get(MyRestSvc.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.ProxyEJB$Handler.invoke(ProxyEJB.java:74)
    at aaa.bbb.ccc.war.MyRestSvc$$LocalBeanProxy.get(aaa/bbb/ccc/war/MyRestSvc.java)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.OpenEJBEJBInvoker.performInvocation(OpenEJBEJBInvoker.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.OpenEJBEJBInvoker.invoke(OpenEJBEJBInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT e FROM Employee e]. 
[14, 22] The abstract schema type 'Employee' is unknown.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1741)
    ... 71 more
-
-
-
```

***pom.xml...***

```
(removed for space - can provide on request)
```

***Environment info...***

```
java 10

EclipseLink (2.7.1)

Dockerized Db2express-c

apache-tomee-7.0.5-plume
```

Comment: @nullpointer it is quite obviously not an duplicate.  And you must have misunderstood: It is the entity's name in the JPQL, not the table name.  So OP is actually correct.

Comment: @nullpointer I don't think that should matter; it's a JPQL query, not a native one.

Comment: @sairn: couldn't see the problem from the quoted info, but it seems that the emf is not properly constructed, and it just don't understand what is "Employee".  It could be problem in the persistence.xml or some other thing.  Are there any log giving u evidence that persistence.xml are properly loaded during startup?

Comment: Check the logs from before the login logic, as it should log each entity as it processes it during the deployment phase. First guess is it is loading a persistence unit that doesn't have your Employee entity - maybe an old version is on your server class path, it hasn't been redeployed correctly etc.

Comment: added portion of log that resulted from GET operation call

Comment: Docker? Why the docker tag?

Comment: felt it could be relevant since the db2express-c database that is connected to is "dockerized" - i.e., runs in a Docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an incompatibility with EclipseLink 2.7.1, somehow.  When I changed to use EclipseLink 2.7.2, the issue disappeared. Thanks to all for comments, suggestions.

I took a hint from this posting: 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1092642/

which referenced this bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532882

```
    <!--does not work...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>  
    -->

    <!-- works as expected...-->     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Java 10 + EL 2.7.3 or Java 8 + EL 2.7.1 combination works. EL 2.7.1 with java 10 doesn't work.